# Java heap space error when calling multiple times JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have the following code where I read xml file, get element values and store data into ACCESS database.

```
    private JdbcTemplate template; 
    modelMap.addAttribute("file", file);
    String xmlString = new String (file.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
    Document doc = convertStringToDocument(xmlString);

    //Normalize XML structure
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("S080_Child");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
         ....
         int insert;
         try {
             insert = template.update("INSERT INTO tblE125Details (ForeasCode, EYear, ArProtokolou, InvNo, SName, Fname, DOB, sex, IDno, entipo, EKAANo,"
                + "EKAAIssueDate, EKAAExpireDate, PaymentAmount, PaymentCurrency, HospFrom, HospTo, MedClaim, InDate)"
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                 institutionID.substring(0,2), MedClaim.substring(6), 
                 globalCLAReferenceCreditorLiaisonBody, individualCLANumberCreditorLiaisonBody,familyName, 
                 forename, dateBirth, sexDescription, pINPersonInCompetentMemberState,db_entipo, eHICNumber, db_EKAAIssueDate, db_EKAAExpireDate, 
                 TotalIndividualAmountBenefits_amount, TotalIndividualAmountBenefits_currency,
                 ProvidedBenefits_BenefitsPeriod_startDate, ProvidedBenefits_BenefitsPeriod_endDate, MedClaim, InDate);
         }
         catch (InvalidResultSetAccessException e) 
         {
             System.out.println("InvalidResultSetAccessException");
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         } 
         catch (DataAccessException e)
         {
             System.out.println("DataAccessException");
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
         catch (Exception e){
             System.out.println("Exception");
             throw new Exception(e);
         }
```

However, I'm getting the following error:
[image]

Comment: You can use JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate to allow batches of inserts instead of single  insert call per record. This will help you improve performance.

Comment: How big is the XML file?  Are you setting any memory parameters for Tomcat?

Comment: I can't read that screen shot.  Too small, too dark, poor contrast.  Cut & paste the error text into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you post (and as stdunbar points out), it seems that the OOM exception can be caused by the processing of the whole XML file that you are fully loading into memory.

So, if the XML file is really big, it would be necessary to process it on the fly instead of loading it entirely in memory before processing its contents.

In order to do so, you will need to: (1) get an input stream for the file instead of reading the contents with getBytes, and (2) use streaming to process the XML contents instead of reading its complete DOM model. You can take a look at: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jaxp-streaming-api.html#stax

Then, if your OOM problem comes from the size of the XML, and these two changes avoid the OOM, you can also apply JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate (as shazin points out) in order to improve performance of the overall process. When using batchUpdate with really large batches, you should limit also the size of the batch: in the last Spring versions there is a batchUpdate form that allows to specify batch size: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.Collection-int-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter-